# Constructing a zero magnetic field in the center of a loop using Biot-Savart

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

An infinitely long wire is oriented like the drawing below.

[image]

The wire with a given current I follows the path of 2 tangent lines to the circle of radius $R$ and an arc around the corner $\theta$.
$\theta$ needs to be calculated so that the magnetic field at the centre of the circle is 0.

I already know that the Biot-Savart law has to be used and that two tangents to the circle have to be constructed so that the magnetic field becomes $0$, but I have a bit trouble constructing the integral for this problem.

$$B=\int dB=\int\frac{\mu_0I \sin(\theta)}{4\pi r^2}dl =\int\frac{\mu_0I \vec{dl}\times \hat r}{4\pi r^2}dl $$

But I have no idea how to construct the dimensions for this problem. I tried to simplify the problem using trigonometry, but it's seemed way too difficult. What can I do?

Comment: I apologize, this was not the right drawing. I will modify my question soon, so this is clearer. Thank you for addressing this issue.

Comment: This was the right drawing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this problem. No answers needed. The answer was 2 radians btw.

Comment: Have you a proof ??? Why not 2.34567  radians ???

Comment: If you have solved your own problem and no answers needed then I suggest to delete this post (question and answer).

Comment: For some reason, I can't seem to delete it.

Comment: No matter, leave them as they are. You couldn't delete  because of low reputation I think.